# C#/WPF - Cannot add RowDefinition into Grid OnVisualChildrenChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

that will automatically add children into separate row. So I make own grid, add method to add new rows and handle it to OnVisualChildrenChanged. But anytime I'm adding new UIElement into it, RowDefinitions.IsReadOnly property is true and I cannot do that.

```
public class GridWithAutoRows : Grid
{
    public void AddRow()
    {
        this.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
    }

    protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)
    {

        this.AddRow();
        Grid.SetRow(visualAdded as UIElement, this.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);

        base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any idea.